# Incorrect alphabetical order of column values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the dataframe below:

```
AS<-c("Composite", "DGIdb", "DrugBank", "DrugCentral_Human",
      "Repurposing", "LINCS_Data_Portal","TargetCentral")
ASe<-c("Composite", "DGIdb", "DrugBank", "DrugCentral (Human)",
       "Drug Repurposing Hub", "LINCS Data Portal","TargetCentral")
d<-data.frame(AS,ASe)
```

and I try to order it alphabetically based on the `ASe` column

```
d[order(d$ASe),]
```

The result I get is :

```
 AS                  ASe
1         Composite            Composite
2             DGIdb                DGIdb
5       Repurposing Drug Repurposing Hub
3          DrugBank             DrugBank
4 DrugCentral_Human  DrugCentral (Human)
6 LINCS_Data_Portal    LINCS Data Portal
7     TargetCentral        TargetCentral
```

but I think that `DrugBank` and `DrugCentral (Human)` should be before `Drug Repurposing Hub` since the letters B and C come before the letter R. What am I missing?

Comment: `d<-data.frame(AS,ASe, stringsAsFactors =FALSE)` or `d[order(as.character(d$ASe)),]`

Comment: It should be `d[order(as.character(d$ASe)),]`

Comment: both give the same incorrect result to me

Comment: If you try `sort(c("B", " ", "C"))` it gives you `" " "B" "C"` so the result is correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the problem is that the columns in your data frame are not characters but factors. Most of the time, it is more convenient to work with characters. In this case you can use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` inside `data.frame(...)`.
Then you can order with respect to the second column:

```
d2 <- data.frame(AS,ASe, stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
d2[order(d2$ASe),]
                 AS                  ASe
1         Composite            Composite
2             DGIdb                DGIdb
5       Repurposing Drug Repurposing Hub
3          DrugBank             DrugBank
4 DrugCentral_Human  DrugCentral (Human)
6 LINCS_Data_Portal    LINCS Data Portal
7     TargetCentral        TargetCentral
```

As you can see, the second column `ASe` is in correct alphabetical order. A space string (i.e `" "`) comes before every letter. Therefore, `Drug Repurposing Hub` is before `DrugBank`.

If you insist on putting space last you can use a workaround like this:

```
d2[order(gsub(" ", "z", d2$ASe)),]
                 AS                  ASe
1         Composite            Composite
2             DGIdb                DGIdb
3          DrugBank             DrugBank
4 DrugCentral_Human  DrugCentral (Human)
5       Repurposing Drug Repurposing Hub
6 LINCS_Data_Portal    LINCS Data Portal
7     TargetCentral        TargetCentral
```

**EDIT:**
the solution Ben Bolker suggested is even better:

```
d2[order(gsub(" ", "", d2$ASe)),]
```